# VMExtensionProvisioningError-VM has reported a failure when processing extension ScriptExtGVM on Azure with informatica bdm

Tags: azure, informatica

While i try to deploy Informatica BDM 10.2 from Azure market place, I receive an error at the end of the deployment.

TYPE

> Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions

STATUSMESSAGE

> { "status": "Failed", "error": { "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
>   "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal
>   provisioning state 'Failed'.", "details": [ { "code":
>   "VMExtensionProvisioningError", "message": "VM has reported a failure
>   when processing extension 'ScriptExtGVM'. Error message: \"Malformed
>   status file [ExtensionError] Invalid status/status: failed\"." } ] } }

RESOURCE

> infa1/ScriptExtGVM

Note: infa1 is the Virtual machine name

Comment: how exactly are you deploying it

Comment: Informatica BDM  is available in market place. So when I access the BDM 10.2 from there, there are few steps available as template and i need to configure it including the exisitng HDInsight cluster and virtual machine  for infa server .